# bug? When Reviewing "Leave Close" button asks to Re-open

Tags: bug, status-completed

This has happened to me several times now: When processing the [Review](https://gis.stackexchange.com/review) queue and I click the button labelled `Leave Closed` a dialogue pops up asking *"Nominate this question for reopening? [OK] [Cancel]"*, which is the opposite of what I intended.

Pressing [Cancel] at this point seems to have the desired effect, leaving the Q closed.

[image: screenshot: Nominate this question for reopening?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, there was a simple but still very bad JavaScript bug on the deploy there...it's resolved now.

Comment: thank you Nick!   .